# excel vba dynamic values with blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to vba, i need to take two values in a worksheet.Example below:

B10=Date........N10=: ...... P10=Feb-15....

the range of B10 have the date,N10 have the colon and P10 have date value, C10:O10 have empty cells.

so everytime i have to give

Selection.End(xlToRight).Select.

How to take this value dynamic.

Date                                                :       Feb-15
Date                                                :       Mar-15
Date                                                :       Apr-15
Date                                                :       May-15
Date                                                :       Jun-15
Date                                                :       Jul-15
Date                                                :       Aug-15
Date                                                :       Sep-15
Date                                                :       Oct-15
Date                                                :       Nov-15
Date                                                :       Dec-15

Anyone please help.

Comment: This is hard to understand? Can you explain in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Excel Macros = "bad code", they always use "selection" object and .Select method when they're not needed...

I can't really tell what you're trying to do, but if it's simply to concatenate those three cells, you can use something like:

```
for i = 1 to intLastRow
    with wsWorksheet
        .cells(i,1) = .cells(i,2) & .cells(i, 13) & .cells(i, 15)
    end with
next
```

But I don't really get the question. Why not just have a formula in a column `="Date: " & text(P10, "mmm-dd")`